# How to put the buttons in the right place (space between two buttons)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, button

Here I have such a code:

```
<div class="float-right">
  <button
    type"btn btn-primary"
    (click)="openInvoiceModal(id!)"
    [tooltip]="open.invoice.modal.tooltip"
    placement"bottom"
    {{ open.invoice.model.label }}
  </button
</div>
<div class="float-right">
  <button
    type"btn btn-primary"
    (click)="closeInvoiceModal(id!)"
    [tooltip]="close.invoice.modal.tooltip"
    placement"bottom"
    {{ close.invoice.model.label }}
  </button
</div>
```

Two buttons, but they are too close to each other (see example below) and I would like to add a space between them.

[image: buttons]

And as you can see despite the fact that the first in the code is the button with the `openInvoiceModal` function, the first button is set to `closeInvoiceModal` that is `button2` on the left. And it should be the other way around.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [margin utility classes](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/utilities/spacing/) to add padding/margins between elements, which will help you get the spacing between buttons that you are looking for.

As for Button2 being rendered to the left of Button1, try wrapping in a single `float-right` class rather than in one class per button. The [float](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/layout/float/) class only applies to the remainder of the parent div available; as you have already floated Button1 to the far right, Button2 can only be placed in the next rightmost position available.